# Persian calendar for Bot Framework

Tags: c#, calendar, botframework, chatbot, persian-calendar

I'm new in Bot Framework technology and  have a question for date picker, is there any way to show persian calender instead of DateInput element in Microsoft Bot Framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't a feature of Bot Framework at this time. It should be noted, however, that the Bot Framework SDKs are open source and there are a number of libraries available that could be integrated to fit your needs. It will require some work to get right, but theoretically, it should be possible.

That having been said, be aware that the different channels (i.e. FaceBook, MS Teams, etc.) don't all support features in the same way. So, you may find that a Persian calendar will work in some channels but not render in others.

Best of luck!